# How to perform spatial queries without coordinate range limitations in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I learned from official documents about Mongodb's spatial query capabilities. But this function has limitations on the latitude and longitude of coordinates,as shown below
"
mongodb document url:https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/geospatial-queries/#std-label-geospatial-queries
Valid longitude values are between -180 and 180, both inclusive.
Valid latitude values are between -90 and 90, both inclusive.
"
I want to store some GeoObjects such as points, polylines, and the points of these shapes are not within the restricted range

Do mongodb have a solution or alternative for this situation

example:

```
# 1、Insert Geo data

db.places.insertMany( [
   {
      loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -2273.97, 1220.77 ] },
      name: "Central Park",
      category : "Park"
   },
   {
      loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -3273.88, 4120.78 ] },
      name: "La Guardia Airport",
      category: "Airport"
   },
   {
      loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -1321.83, 52311.18 ] },
      name: "Stonehenge",
      category : "Monument"
   }
] )

# 2、Create index and throw an error
caused by :: Can't extract geo keys, loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -2273.97, 1220.77 ] }, \
name: "Central Park", category: "Park" }  
longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: -2273.97 lat: 1220.77
```